Why are there no occurrences of חיסורי מחסרא in the non-talmudic Tractates?
The Talmud occasionally utilises a Method of Last Resort called "חיסורי מחסרא", essentially "insert words here", to explain away a blatant incongruency or inherent difficulty in reading a Mishna (for example; a non sequitur, a contradiction from one sentence to the next, or a counterproof that undermines the statement that it is intended to prove).
This insertion often drastically changes the simple meaning of the mishna.
The Talmud that is extant covers 37 of 63 Mishnaic tractates, and yet somehow, from the remaining 26, the Mishnaic commentators were not required to resort to the principle of חיסורי מחסרא to explain any discrepancies.
Is this a massive coincidence? Or did רבי יהודה הנשיא somehow foresee the loss of the missing talmudic tractates, and word the mishnayot accordingly?

The later commentators "did not deem it necessary"? I suspect it's "did not feel they had the authority."

@ Shalom. I agree. The Amoraim would have the authority to utilize such a device. The rishonim and achronim who comment on Mishna - now that's a different matter.

@Shalom I edited a bit. my point is that the problems solved by a חיסורי מחסרא are usually blatant and unsolvable otherwise. Take a מעשה לסתור for example.

Note that the Bavli also analyzes mishnayos and baraisos from other tractates. | This article is relevant to your topic.

I wonder if those mishnayos could have been emended in place to reflect the correct understanding, whereas the ones with accompanying gemara were preserved as-is (as is often the preference with corrections to canonical texts).

Why do you assume that the tractates were lost?

I have several thoughts here: Are we sure that the Talmud Bavli does not use the Chasurei Michsarei fix when quoting Mishnayot from tractates that have no Talmud Bavli on them? Does the Yerushalmi utilize Chasurei Michsirah on those tractates that have no Talmud Bavli on them?  BTW, I found this commentary on a tractate that has no Talmud on it (Keilim). He employs Chasurei Michsarah. Where does he get it from? Is he using it on his own? מלאכת שלמה מסכת כלים פרק ה משנה ד ומשני לה וכן נ"ל ג"כ לפרש הכא חסורי מחסרא והכי קא תני תנור שהוסק וכו', –

@GratefulD wow. that's what I call bekius!

@GratefulD The M'leches Sh'lomo used the language of חסורי מחסרא, but his point was merely that the halacha is a matter of dispute and that this mishna was only אליבא דרבן גמליאל (see the anecdote at the end of the mishna) even though the reisha of the mishna wasn't explicitly attributed to him.

I'm taking your statement for granted that it doesn't appear in Mishnaic commentary (other than perhaps the one example found by @GratefulD ... however, you are asking about the specific phrase or term; are you certain than no commentary does a "חסורי מחסרא" type of interpretation without using the expression?
